# read string and output Uppercase letters

Tags: java

I've been struggling with this simple question from an assignment:

My tester class is supposed to read an input called name and my other class
is supposed to have a method that returns only uppercase letters.

My code returns the uppercase letters along with the original input.

Any help would go a long way.

```
public static String pleaseGetUpperCase(String name){
    for (int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(i))==true){
            System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
            //String name = Character.toString(name.charAt(i)); 
        }
    }   return name;
}
```

Comment: Just saying, but a regex would solve this so easily. `String upper = name.replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");`.

Comment: Create a StringBuilder with the upper case characters and toString() it.

Comment: You don't need the `==true` in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method provided by you doesn't RETURN only the uppercase characters, it just prints them and returns the original. this could do the job:

```
public static String pleaseGetUpperCase(String name){
    String uppercaseCharacters = "";
    for (int i=0;i<name.length();i++){
        char ch = name.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
            uppercaseCharacters += ch;
        }
    }   
    return uppercaseCharacters;
}
```

Side note: comparing with true inside an if-condition is not really useful.

Comment: The use of a `StringBuilder` for appending would be more appropriate.

Comment: You're right. I just guessed from the context of the question that introducing this kind of 'object oriented distraction' might be confusing to a rookie :)

Comment: @LeuX Thanks a ton..I was stuck for a long time :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try something like this:

```
public String getUpperCase(final String string){
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(final char c : string.toCharArray())
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
            builder.append(c);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..without the statement `return name`

```
public static String pleaseGetUpperCase(String name){

    for (int i=0;i<name.length();i++){

        if (Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(i))){


            System.out.print(name.charAt(i));    
        }
    } 
    return "";
}
```

This function will print the upper case letters in your string.. If you want it to be `returned` then you can create an object of `StringBuilder` and append the the upper case characters to it and then return the data `StringBuilder` object as a `String`.

```
public static String pleaseGetUpperCase(String name){

    StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();



    for (int i=0;i<name.length();i++){

        if (Character.isUpperCase(name.charAt(i))){

         SB.append(name.charAt(i);

        }
    } 
    return (SB.toString());

}
```

Comment: This won't even compile though? The return type is a `String` and you are not returning anything.

Comment: @JoshM : Please refer to the edit. I apologize for the incorrect version.